Screen Flow - refresh Data Table on date input change
I have a Flow that shows records in the Data Table.
The first action is Get Records that filters records by date. Right now it is formula - today(). But there is a request to have an input so a User can select needed date and only records that match the criteria are displayed in the Data Table.
I really woul like to have this Date input on the same screen as the Data Table, but I don't see a way to refresh the table and force the Flow to run Get Records with the new value for the filter.
I assume I need to have yet another Screen with Date input, then Get Records action, then Screen with the Data Table. This is super ugly and as not user-friendly as possible.
Is there any way to re-query records with the new value and refresh the Data Table on the same screen?

You can do this, but not without custom code. You would create a Flow Screen Component that acts as the date filter input, and when the value changes, use the methods from lightning-flow-support to set a variable using FlowAttributeChangeEvent that will be used in a Decision to loop back to the Get Records element, and then use the FlowNavigationNextEvent to trigger Get Records and an Assignment to reset the variable used for navigating back around.
